# LINQ filtering between two times and by hour

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query that is currently like this:

```
var query = from l in Records
            where l.time >= time1 && l.time <= time2
            select l;
```

however, the Records collection used to log once every two seconds, now it logs once an hour. I need a way of only grabbing one Record an hour from the old data, so that the returned data makes more sense, and so I don't return months of data logged every 2 seconds...Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you explain  your requirement more exactly since it doesn't make much sense for me. You only need one record per hour, so this query should return the last record in the last hour or what?

Comment: I need a list of Records that are all between time1 and time2, but only one per hour. So, if time1 = "09/5/2012 - 14:00" and time2 = "09/05/2012 - 16:00" and Records contained items 1. "09/5/2012 - 14:00" 2."09/5/2012 - 14:30" 3."09/5/2012 - 15:22", and 4."09/5/2012 - 16:00". I'd need items 1, 3 and 4. I hope that clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you want only one record per hour. That means you need to group by hour:

```
var query = records
            .Where(r => r.time >= time1 && r.time <= time2)
            .Select(r => new
            {
                Hour = new DateTime(r.time.Year, r.time.Month, r.time.Day, r.time.Hour, 0, 0),
                Record = r
            })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Hour)
            .Select(grp => grp.First().Record);
```

Comment: A quick note: This won't work in LINQ-to-Entities. That only supports parameterless constructors and initializers.

Comment: @ThomasG: You haven't mentioned that this is LINQ-to-Entities. Anyway, i'm not really familiar with it, but it should be possible to create anonymous types like i did. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/49a23b65-cdf8-4f58-b4a0-4effbe10c1ae/

Answer (score 1):

You should group by hour and select the first element for each hour.

Try this:

```
var query = from l in Records
            where l.time >= time1 && l.time <= time2
            group l by l.time.Hour into g
            select g.First();
```

Comment: This would group all days hour into one. Consider OP has every hour at least one record. He wants ~30*24 records per month. Your query would return only 24 records(even for the whole year).